# SonarQube shows projectKey is null, but it is defined in sonar-project.properties

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

When we want to analyze a JavaScript project we make use of `sonar-project.properties` file. We specify the `projectKey` in this file. We also specify the `sonar.branch` property so that we can create branch specific project in SonarQube. But when we run the `sonar-scanner` we always get to see `null` in the dashboard of SonarQube. We are using SonarQube and SonarQube scanner latest versions.

Comment: Did you define `projectKey` or `sonar.projectKey`? Please paste your `sonar-project.properties` file.

Comment: Are you passing the sonar.branch as a Java argument? I'm having the same issue when is pass it as a argument.